# Set up Sync Manager - Option is missing

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Trying to get a test connection on the quickbooks API, but am running into a strange issue.

When testing my new created app space, I need to:

```
Go to QuickBooks. Open your company file.
Choose File > Set Up Intuit Sync Manager.
Sign in with your Intuit account if you haven't already done so.
Come back after Intuit Sync Manager is done syncing
```

My quickbooks does not have the : Set up Sync Manager : Option.

Scouring the quicbooks support docs and quickbooks telephone support, I have tried the following:

```
Re-orderd the "lists" in quickbooks, and repaired company file.. No go...
Made sure the company is accessed with the Admin account.
Tried by creating a completely fresh company, on my local machine, and directly after that, looking for the option.. no go (Did exit and restart Quickbooks)
Verified that the Syncmanager app is installed (resides) on my pc... C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intuit\Sync\IntuitSyncManager.exe 
I can run the sync manager, and it appears in my taskbar, but tells me it has no company files to sync. Obviously, this needs to be configured from Quickbooks, which does not have the option.
```

Platform:
Windows 7, Windows 8, Terminal Services 2003 (All have the option missing)
Quickbooks Enterprise 13 (South Africa), believe its the UK version.

Looking forward to any help.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Only US versions of QuickBooks work with Sync Manager.